# I want to create a composite types names DeptRecord and accept the values from the user and insert the accepted values into the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  TYPE DEPTRECORD IS RECORD (
    IDEPTNO NUMBER := &deptno,
    SDEPTNAME VARCHAR2(150) := &deptname,
    SDEPTLOC VARCHAR2(150) := &deptloc
  );

  DEP_REC DEPTRECORD;

BEGIN

Insert into department(deptno,deptname,deptloc) values(&deptno,'&deptname','&deptloc');
commit;

END;
```

Comment: You haven't said what issue you are having - though there are some fairly obvious ones. But why do you want to use PL/SQL and a record type - just running the `insert` on its own seems sufficient? (Assuming you're using a client that understands and prompts for substitution variables; you've tagged two clients...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I can directly insert but I want to do it in this way what I have coded. Could you please let me know what went wrong. Because it's throwing an error. I want to accept the values from the user and want to insert the records into the department table(which has deptno, deptname, deptloc) columns.

Comment: Please at least include the full error message in your question. The insert on its own will accept the values from the user - is this an assignment specifically to use a record for the insert?

Comment: Yes @AlexPoole. Error is like whatever I am giving say Deptname as 'Sales' so its throwing error identifier 'Sales' must be declared

Comment: @AlexPoole This is the question :

Comment: Create a composite type named DeptRecord ( iDeptno, sDeptName, sDeptLoc) as 
attributes with appropriate datatypes and accept the value for these attributes from the 
user as mentioned below :-
i. iDeptNo : Value should be Max(deptno) From the “Department” Table 
and increment 1 to it.
ii. sDeptName : must be a not null string with <= 21 characters
iii. sDeptLoc : Can be either “BDC” or “CDC” or “HDC”
 If the above conditions are met insert the above record to the “Department” table.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69012402/edit) to add significant information - including the *full* error message.

Comment: [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html) and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) are both developer tools. Are those what your users really have for running scripts?

Comment: You declare a type `dept record` but you don't use it. Also, strings like `&deptname` need to be quoted, e.g. `'&deptname'`. If you are really using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) then it has tools for prompting interactively which you won't find in SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus, so the exact client tool is important for answering the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error is like whatever I am giving say Deptname as 'Sales' so its throwing error identifier 'Sales' must be declared

That is because your first references to `deptname` and `deptloc` are not quoted; in the record type definition:

```
SDEPTNAME VARCHAR2(150) := &deptname
SDEPTLOC VARCHAR2(150) := &deptloc
```

should be

```
SDEPTNAME VARCHAR2(150) := '&deptname'
SDEPTLOC VARCHAR2(150) := '&deptloc'
```

as you already did in the `insert ... values()` clause.

The way you've defined the type is setting the default values from the substitution variables; as this is a one-off instance anyway it doesn't make much difference, but your tutor might be expecting you to populate the *instance* of that type with the values, not the defaults.

You might want to set the record field/attribute data types using, for example, `department.deptno%type` - but it depends how you want to do the validation part of the assignment.

At the moment you'll be prompted twice for the values because you are using `&` rather than `&&`. But you don't need two references - you can refer to your record in the insert:

```
Insert into department(deptno,deptname,deptloc)
values(dep_rec.ideptno, dep_rec.sdeptname, dep_rec.sdeptloc);
```

If the record type included all columns from the table then you could insert the entire record in one go, without referring to the fields/attributes individually - but that probably isn't the case here.